# How do I serial print a constant single string and a changing variable within it?

Tags: serial

I want to print a single line including the variable "val" only once rather than looping or repeating of the same line and within it the val will change according to the reading. Is it possible? If so, how?

[image]

```cpp
#define trigPin 5
#define echoPin 6

float distance(uint8_t T, uint8_t H);

void setup()
{
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.print("The object is: ");
}

void loop()
{
    float val = distance(32, 68);
    Serial.print(val);
    Serial.println(" cm away");
    delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question. Please show us some code that you have. It can be the code that you want to run and that does not work. Tell us what you expect and what you get instead.

Comment: What? Sorry, I don't understand, what you mean

Comment: You want to print something like “result: 123”, and the replace “123” with other values within the same line, without printing other lines. Did I correctly guess what your question is about? PS: People shouldn't have to guess, you should put your best effort into making the question clear enough.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, what's the fun in that? Don't you want to play 20 questions? :)

Answer (score 1):

> within it [the already printed line] the val will change according to
> the reading

This “within it” makes little sense. “Printing” is just sending bytes
through the serial port, and you don't choose where these bytes are
going: you just send them one at a time. The program you use as a
“serial port monitor” then displays those bytes in whatever manner it
sees fit. You cannot control from the Arduino where things get
displayed.

Or maybe you can...

If your monitor program can emulate an [old school terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal), then
it can understand special control sequences, including [escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code),
that instruct it to perform specific actions, such as moving the cursor
or erasing part of the screen. Suitable terminal emulators include
[screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) on Linux and MacOS, and [Putty](https://www.putty.org/) on Windows. You may find
something appropriate for your mobile platform. Notably, the Arduino
serial monitor is *not* a terminal emulator, and doesn't interpret those
control sequences.

Assuming you are using a suitable terminal emulator, the simplest
solution to your problem is to just repeat the whole sentence “The
object is: xx.xx cm away” for every measurement, but do so by
overwriting the current line instead of moving to the next one. You thus
replace `Serial.println()` by `Serial.print()`, and precede each
sentence by a carriage return character (ASCII CR = `0x0d` = `'\r'`),
which is interpreted as the command “move the cursor to the start of the
line”:

```cpp
void loop() {
    float val = distance(32, 68);
    Serial.print("\rThe object is: ");  // note the '\r'
    Serial.print(val);
    Serial.print(" cm away");  // no println()
    delay(500);
}
```

There is a caveat here. If you overwrite a sentence (say “The object is:
10.07 cm away”) by a shorter one (“The object is: 9.92 cm away”, one
character less), the previous sentence will not be completely
overwritten, so you may end up with “awayy” showing on the display. This
can be overcome by ensuring a fixed-length formatting of the numbers
displayed, by padding with spaces, or by sending an “erase current line”
command to the terminal.

As a side note, what `Serial.println()` does is print what you
requested, followed by a CR character, and then a line feed character
(ASCII LF = `0x0a` = `'\n'`). The line feed is interpreted by the
terminal as the command “move the cursor to the next line, without
changing its horizontal position”.

If you find it annoying to repeatedly print “The object is:”, you can
instead use more advanced control sequences. For instance:

- “<ESC>[16G” means “move the cursor to column 16”
- “<ESC>[K” means “clear from the cursor to the end of the line”

where <ESC> is the escape character:

```cpp
void loop() {
    float val = distance(32, 68);
    Serial.print("\x1b[16G\x1b[K");  // "\x1b" is the escape character
    Serial.print(val);
    Serial.print(" cm away");
    delay(500);
}
```